# Invalid config results returned from titanium. (JSON parse error)

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-phone-8.1, titanium, appcelerator

After installing the node packages in a windows 10 machine for a hybrid app  using

npm install appcelerator -g

the modules get installed however while checking the environment the following error appears which says json parse error from titanium. please check screen share for more details.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks-section-43306725_AppceleratorCLITasks-InstallNode.js

appc setup

[image]

Comment: might be a windows 10 issue. But I would suggest contacting Appcelerator

Comment: We are using a trial version. However the issue seems to be with VS15 and W10